# How to make sure a chosen font is displayed on every os and devices?

Tags: android, ios, web, fonts

According to my understanding every OS has its supported fonts. If a site is using another font that is not supported by an operating system, then a default font will be shown, like on Android the roboto.
At the same time I have come across sites that are using a font that is clearly not on the iOS font list, yet on all devices including iphones and ipads and all other operating systems it is displayed right.
So how is that possible? Is there a solution around this problem? 
Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

Using CSS3's [`@font-face`](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_font-face_rule.asp) rule, you can now specify your own font name and font file:

```
@font-face {
    font-family: myFirstFont;
    src: url(sansation_light.woff);
}
```

Then to use the font, use the `font-family` property:

```
div {
    font-family: myFirstFont;
}
```

[Google has tons of free web fonts](https://www.google.com/fonts) that you can include in your HTML/CSS.

Comment: Thanks Marcus! Do you know if this rule applies to Android too?

Comment: Yes, any modern browser (or web component) will support CSS3.

Comment: Thanks and just a final question if you allow me: Based on your experience will the @font-face rule increase page load time (because the fonts will need to be downloaded before the page can be rendered...) especially on mobile devices?

Comment: Font files are small. One font file that I use is [30K](http://cocblog.com). On a graphics intensive page, it's hardly a blip. If you're trying to theme a page, sometimes it's worth the extra page load to match the font.